# MSQL SUM over partition command gives error

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySQL following is not working.

```
CREATE TABLE Sales(  
    Employee_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
    Year INT NOT NULL,  
            Country VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
    Product VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,  
    Sale DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY(Employee_Name, Year)  
);

INSERT INTO Sales(Employee_Name, Year, Country, Product, Sale)  
VALUES
('Joseph', 2017, 'India', 'Laptop', 10000),  
('Joseph', 2018, 'India', 'Laptop', 15000),  
('Joseph', 2019, 'India', 'TV', 20000),  
('Bob', 2017, 'US', 'Computer', 15000),  
('Bob', 2018, 'US', 'Computer', 10000),  
('Bob', 2019, 'US', 'TV', 20000),  
('Peter', 2017, 'Canada', 'Mobile', 20000),  
('Peter', 2018, 'Canada', 'Calculator', 1500),  
('Peter', 2019, 'Canada', 'Mobile', 25000);  

SELECT Year, Product, Sale, SUM(Sale)   
OVER(PARTITION BY Year) AS Total_Sales   
FROM Sales;
```

The query gives following error
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

> An alias was previously found. (near "Total_Sales" at position 69)
> An alias was expected. (near " " at position 68)
> Unexpected token. (near "Total_Sales" at position 69)
> SQL query: Copy Documentation

```
SELECT Year, Product, Sale, SUM(Sale) OVER(PARTITION BY Year) AS Total_Sales FROM Sales;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY Year) AS Total_Sales
> FROM Sales' at line 2

I am trying to get Mysql window functions LEAD / LAG to work on my MAMP installation

Comment: I assume you are using a version earlier than 8? This works fine in MySQL v8, but earlier versions do not support window functions. In that case, you can create a subquery or CTE to get the total_sales as one option.

Comment: I am using mysql version 14 that is bundled with latest MAMP download

Comment: There isn't a mysql version 14 please publish the result of select version():